# Why $W\cap V\neq\emptyset$ in this proof?

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

I dont understand the following proof:

> **Lemma.** Let $X$ be normal, $C$ closed, and $U$ open with $C \subseteq U$. Then there exists an open set $V$ such that $C \subseteq V \subseteq \operatorname{cl}(V ) \subseteq  U$.
>
> **Proof.** Since $C$ and $U^\complement $ are disjoint closed sets, by normality there exist disjoint open sets $V\supseteq C$ and $W \supseteq U^\complement $. If $x\in\operatorname{cl}(V )\cap  U^\complement $, then $W$ , as a neighborhood of $x$, meets $V$, a contradiction. Therefore $\operatorname{cl}(V)\subseteq W$.$\Box$

I guess that the expression "$W$ meets $V$" means that $V\cap W\neq \emptyset $, however I cannot see why. I mean: if $W$ is a neighborhood of $x$ and $x\in \partial V$ then I dont see why necessarily $V\cap W\neq \emptyset $. Can someone enlighten me, please?

Comment: Another way to see it: we know that $V \cap W= \emptyset$, so $V \subseteq W^\complement$, and so $\overline{V} \subseteq \overline{W^\complement}=W^\complement \subseteq U$, as $W^\complement$ is closed and $U^\complement \subseteq W$ is equivalent to $W^\complement \subseteq U$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because we are assuming that $x\in\overline V$. Therefore, by the definition of closure, every neighborhood $W$ of $x$ meets $V$ (that is, $W\cap V\neq\emptyset$).

Comment: right, very easy after all. Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.